# Decrement a field and delete entire object if field's value reaches to 0 in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a Chat room mechanism and for this I am using nodejs,mongodb and mangoose.
I want to delete entire row if  "count" field reaches to "0".

So far I have this function which increase and decreases the count field successfully, but want to delete the object when count =0. How can I achieve this using below method.

```
function addOrRemoveFromRoom(mRoom, userCount) {
        ModelRooms.findByIdAndUpdate(mRoom.id, {
            $inc: { count: userCount },
            $addToSet: {
                "users": {
                    $each: [mUser],
                }
            }
        }, { returnOriginal: false }, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                logger.error("Error occured", err);
            }
            else {
                logger.info("Success", mRoom.roomName);                
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my schema

```
let roomsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    roomName: String,
    count: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    users: [
        {
            userId: String,            
            created: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

How can i delete entire object if **count** field reaches to 0 (Zero)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "findAndModify"
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/